# Nokia Qt: App compiles for Qt Simulator, fails to compile for Symbian Device - QFutureWatcher

Tags: qt

I'm writing a Qt app for Symbian. My app does compile and run in Qt simulator , but it fails when compiling for Symbian Device, with the following error:

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QFutureWatcher' with no type
>   expect ';' before '<' token

I have also include:QFutureWatcher

Any idea what's wrong??

Thanks....

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, @Frank is right, please show us the code that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-5182), support for QFuture and QtConcurrent is missing from Symbian.